# Unable to install libx11 on MacOS

Tags: macos, makefile, homebrew

I am trying to install Maven for work via Homebrew and one of the dependencies of Maven is libx11. The problem is that when I run the make script, it fails due to a missing file error (missing stropts.h). Here is the full error log:

```
==> Installing maven dependency: libx11
==> ./configure --prefix=/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libx11/1.8.4 --sysconfdir=/Users/vmishel/homebrew/etc
==> make
Last 15 lines from /Users/vmishel/Library/Logs/Homebrew/libx11/02.make:
/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include/X11/Xtrans/Xtranslcl.c:81:11: fatal error: 'stropts.h' file not found
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c lcCharSet.c -o lcCharSet.o >/dev/null 2>&1
# include <stropts.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c imKStoUCS.c -o imKStoUCS.o >/dev/null 2>&1
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c XDefaultIMIF.c -o XDefaultIMIF.o >/dev/null 2>&1
1 error generated.
make[3]: *** [xim_trans.lo] Error 1
make[3]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c XlcDL.c -o XlcDL.o >/dev/null 2>&1
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c XDefaultOMIF.c -o XDefaultOMIF.o >/dev/null 2>&1
libtool: compile:  clang -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../../src -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../include -I../../include/X11 -I../../src/xcms -I../../src/xkb -I../../src/xlibi18n -I../../src -D_BSD_SOURCE -D_DEFAULT_SOURCE -D_BSD_SOURCE -DHAS_FCHOWN -DHAS_STICKY_DIR_BIT -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxau/1.0.11/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxdmcp/1.1.4/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/libxcb/1.15_1/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -I/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xorgproto/2022.2/include -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wmissing-declarations -Wformat=2 -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wnested-externs -Wbad-function-cast -Wold-style-definition -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wunused -Wuninitialized -Wshadow -Wmissing-noreturn -Wmissing-format-attribute -Wredundant-decls -Werror=implicit -Werror=nonnull -Werror=init-self -Werror=main -Werror=missing-braces -Werror=sequence-point -Werror=return-type -Werror=trigraphs -Werror=array-bounds -Werror=write-strings -Werror=address -Werror=int-to-pointer-cast -Werror=pointer-to-int-cast -fno-strict-aliasing -g -O2 -c lcCT.c -o lcCT.o >/dev/null 2>&1
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1

Do not report this issue to Homebrew/brew or Homebrew/homebrew-core!

These open issues may also help:
libx11 1.8.5 https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/132483
Installing maven has failed!
```

Homebrew suggests this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/pull/132483) as potentially helpful but the PR that is mentioned in here does not work for me either. Building libx11 1.8.5 still fails for me.

Does anyone know of a workaround for either installing Maven or libx11?

Comment: This looks to be the first error you're getting: `/Users/vmishel/homebrew/Cellar/xtrans/1.5.0/include/X11/Xtrans/Xtranslcl.c:81:11: fatal error: 'stropts.h' file not found`  That's for the [optional and obsolescent POSIX STREAMS](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/stropts.h.html#tag_13_53) API.  I suspect it's never been supported on OSX.  Is there a `configure` option to not use POSIX STREAMS?

Comment: @AndrewHenle I'm thinking that I'm surely missing a build option since my colleagues were able to install libx11, however I can't figure out what it is, and looking through the `--help` output for the configure application nothing stands out. The configuration application is able to detect that I'm running arm-apple-darwin22.5.0 architecture...

Comment: Supposing that it's an Autotools build system, running the `configure` script with the `--help` option will tell you about all the supported options, such as any for disabling use of POSIX STREAMS.  On the other hand, if it is an Autotools build system then it's at best a mediocre one, because a good one would recognize and handle the absence of `stropts.h` at configuration time, not `make` time.

Answer (score 1):

You should get `libX11` installed automagically if you install **XQuartz**, which you can install either via **homebrew**:

```
brew install --cask xquartz
```

or directly from the [developer site](https://www.xquartz.org). Mine appeared in `/opt/X11` but it may depend on your CPU architecture (Apple Silicon vs Intel).

Comment: Sorry - updated. And were you able to find the library afterwards?